# tableview cellForRowAt indexPath values not coming outside to use in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, variables

I am getting all values in `cellForRowAt indexPath`, here according to its index i need values.. i am getting row index but i am getting that row values:

**i have button in cell.. so if i click button then i need that cell latitude and longitude**

*here i need `cellForRowAt` latitude, longitude in `openMapForPlace()` but not coming why?**

here is the code:

```
 var latitude: Double!
 var longitude: Double!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return userModel?.userAddresses.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell: AddresCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddresCell", for: indexPath) as! AddresCell
    
    let addr = userModel?.userAddresses![indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self

        cell.name.text    = addr?.type
        cell.typeAddLabel.text = addr?.addressName
                  let street = addr?.streetName
                  let colony = addr?.colony
                  let city   = addr?.city
                   let pincode = addr?.pincode
        let locality: String = addr?.buildingName ?? ""
        let dorNum: String = addr?.houseNo ?? ""
        
        let coord = addr?.location
        latitude = coord?.latitude
        longitude = coord?.longitude
        cell.address.text = street! + "," + colony! + "," + city! + "," + pincode! + "," + locality + "," + dorNum
    print("cellForRowAt indexPath \(indexPath.row) \(latitude), \(longitude)")
    addressStr = street! + "," + colony! + "," + city! + "," + pincode! + "," + locality + "," + dorNum
        
        cell.directions.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

    func btnDirectTapped(cell: AddresCell) {
   if let indexPath = self.addressTableview.indexPath(for: cell)
    {
    openMapForPlace()
    print("selecte coordinates222 \(latitude!), \(longitude!)")
        
        print("tableview row indexpath dir btn\(indexPath.row)")
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
   
   }

func openMapForPlace() {
    print("selecte coordinates1111 \(latitude!), \(longitude!)")

               let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
               let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 77.5946)
               let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
               let options = [
                   MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
                   MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
               ]
               let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
               let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
               mapItem.name = "Place Name"
               mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to take values from model not from cell. Set button tag in your cellForRow and get tag to get  userAddresses

```
func openMapForPlace(index:Int) {
 let addr = userModel?.userAddresses![index]

}
```

you can do that like

```
func btnDirectTapped(cell: AddresCell) {
   if let indexPath = self.addressTableview.indexPath(for: cell)
    {
    openMapForPlace(index: indexPath.row)
    print("selecte coordinates222 \(latitude!), \(longitude!)")
        
        print("tableview row indexpath dir btn\(indexPath.row)")
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
```

}

Comment: cell is lodded with address label.. and button.. if i click button i need to show direction from current location to that row coordinates.. so i am calling `openMapForPlace` in  `btnDirectTapped `

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use force unwrapping (`userModel?.userAddresses![index]`)